# TortoiseGit file add has no effect for a single file

Tags: tortoisegit

I have a single C# file which tortoisegit will not add to source control. Selecting the Tortoise->Add context menu shows the add file dialog. I click OK - no errors.
I then try commit but no files are commitable. When I again select the Tortoise menu, the Add option is again available.
The file still shows the blue question mark icon, indicating that it has not been added.

How do I get this file added?

Comment: The file you are trying to add might be included in the .gitignore file. You could try command line instead of tortoise. "git add ."

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the git repository is corrupt for this file. When I look at the master repo this file has two identical copies and another file from the same directory is missing. I propose to copy them and then delete the two files involved. After committing the deletes I will re-add them.